# Problem about nested escape character

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested

I want to pass jquery command into eval() function but I have found that some situation is not work.

For example, I have

```
$('input[name="lastName"]').val("xxx");
```

Then I pass into eval function

```
eval("$('input[name="lastName"]').val('xxx');");
eval('$('input[name="lastName"]').val('xxx');');
```

Because there are too many " or ' block in this pattern.
Seam it not make sense, how to solve this problem?

Comment: May I ask, why do you need to `eval` a jQuery statement? Surely there's a better way to achieve what you're attempting.

Comment: @karim79 because ่jquery statement will automatic generated, so i can't fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
eval('$("input[name=\'lastName\']").val("xxx")');
```